# PUT/DELETE requests from Firefox and Safari not working in node/express js

Tags: node.js, express, put

I have a node/express application where I don't see the requests proceeding onto PUT or DELETE after hitting OPTIONS when the call is made from Firefox/Safari

Here is my app configuration :

```
var app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    next();
});
```

I am calling the api using fetch

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/testapi/' + id, {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              testDetails: testInfo,
          })
      })
```

GET and POST requests work fine in all the browsers.I am unable to figure out why PUT and DELETE requests are not working in Firefox and Safari. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: how are you calling you API ?

Comment: fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/testapi/' + id, {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              testDetails: testInfo,
          })
      })

Comment: could you share the middlewares responsible of handling put and delete methods? Also, did you figure out what errors firefox and safari are giving you? Or is it an app-level error?